# Selected item in ASP.NET Core razor not being passed

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor for the first time. I'm trying to simply set a bound property with the selected value of a dropdown but the property is always null when the form is posted. Also, how does one get the form posted when a selection is made? TIA

Razor page:

```
<td>
    <form method="post">
        <select asp-for="@Model.selectedReport" asp-items="@Model.Reports" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </form>
</td>
```

Code behind:

```
public class SubscribedReportsModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty] 
    public List<SelectListItem> Workspaces { get; private set; }

    [BindProperty] 
    public List<SelectListItem> Reports { get; private set; }

    [BindProperty] 
    public string selectedReport { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        await GetWorkspaces();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        if (selectedReport != null)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a submit button inside that form tag or use ajax to post the form to the code marked with the OnPost convention. It is not clear how do you know that the _selectedReport_ is null if you don't know how to post back from the cshtml to cs

Comment: HI Steve. Holy cow I'm rusty. Yes, all I did was add  onchange="this.form.submit()" to the <select> control and all works fine. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty it appears. All I had to do was add onchange="this.form.submit()" to the  control:

```
                    <td>
                    <form method="post">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.selectedReport" asp-items="@Model.Reports" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                </select>
                        @*@Html.DropDownList("ddl_Reports", Model.Reports, new {@class="form-control"})*@
                        @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedReport, Model.Reports, "--Select Report--", new{@class="form-control"})*@
                    </form>
                </td>
```